# How do I use a php echo inside a short code in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, echo, shortcode

I am trying to define a variable for a plugin using a php variable inside of a shortcode in Wordpress.

What I want to use is this:

```
[wpdatachart id=16 var1="<?php echo um_profile_id(); ?>"]
```

Obviously this won't work, but what is the proper way of writing this?

Comment: Why don't you pull the var inside the shortcode function? You could replicate `um_profile_id()`: http://hookr.io/functions/um_profile_id/

Answer (score 1):

This depends on where you want to add the shortcode.

If you want to add shortcode through some PHP Code than solution provided by "shr3jn" is perfect.

However, if you want to add this in some page than you need to dynamically replace value while wrinting add_shortcode command, using $atts parameter. Refer documentation [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_shortcode)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[wpdatachart id=16 var1="'. um_profile_id().'"]'); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can echo inside shortcode using [`do_shortcode`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_shortcode/) function of wordpress.

```
<?php
    echo do_shortcode( '[shrtcd]' . function() . '[/shrtcd]' );
?>
```

Comment: <?php echo do_shortcode( '[shortcode]' . function() . '[/shortcode]' ); ?>

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[shortcode]'); ?>
```

Replace the shortcode in square bracket with your shortcode.